# Xamarin Android revert back window flags?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I was reading that Xamarin Android had the ability to disable screenshots via `SetFlags`:

```
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
```

I can't figure out what the "default" flags are in the case I want to revert. For example, if I want to go "secure" for a credit card page but then need to `SetFlags` back to what they were previous to this.

There does not appear to be a `GetFlags()` method or a Flags member to Window. Is there a way to figure out what the Flags are so that I turn off "secure" mode?

Comment: You can use DependencyService to achieve it, create two method in the interface. when you show the safe page, enable it by `Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);`, enter the normal page, you can use `Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure);`, but the `Window` need the `Activity`, you can use `CrossCurrentActivity` plugin in the denpendency service to get the `Window` class, you can refer to this thread about Dependency code :https://github.com/851265601/ACommonUtils/blob/master/TakeScreenService

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `Window.ClearFlags` method ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.window.clearflags?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)).

So something like:

```
Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
```